How to optimally transfer potential energy from a large mass to accelerate a small one upwards
With the potential energy of a large mass (say 50 kg at 10 meters high) I want to accelerate a smaller mass (5-25 kg) upwards. I find that simple mechanisms like pulleys, levers, and simple gears leave a lot of kinetic energy in the large mass when it hits the ground.
Is there some clever mechanism that optimally transfers the energy to the small one? Ideally with some combination of levers and/or gears. (Hydraulic or Pneumatic as a last resort)

Your question borders on the vague and as such, risks being closed.
Opinions will come into play, unless you can provide specific energy figures and mechanisms under consideration.
Even with that caveat, have you checked out a trebuchet?

Think about those air bags often seen at beaches.

Hello fred_dot_u , A classic trebuchet is precisely an example of what I mean, that the large mass transfers little energy to the small mass. In the catapult, the mass that goes down conserves a large part of its initial potential energy at the end as kinetic energy. We want a mechanism that allows the maximum energy to be transferred to the mass that goes up.

You may be running into the power vs efficiency tradeoff. Consider that if the large mass reaches 0 velocity, your rate of power transfer will be 0. How much velocity should you leave in the large mass once you are done (right before it hits the ground)?

A trebuchet, with a variable-ratio pulley between the propelling mass and the projectile.  You'll need to tune the pulley geometry to match the two masses and the amount of friction in the system.
Optimal speed is probably achieved if the propelling mass is accelerated at $\frac 1 2 g$ downward for the first half of its travel, then $\frac 1 2 g$ upward for the second half of its travel.  This means that you'll need to trim the pulley so that the propelling mass is loaded by $\frac 1 2$ it's weight for the first half of travel, switching to $\frac 3 2$ it's weight for the second half.
It'll only work for the one propelled mass that you design the mechanism for -- too little mass and you'll have leftover kinetic energy in the propelling mass; too much and the thing won't reach the end of its travel before it reaches zero speed.
It'll only work as designed if the mechanism is perfectly frictionless -- in real life you'll need to adjust the ratio to match the losses.
If you're using the trebuchet for more than one grand piano/car/whatever it's probably easier to just design the trebuchet so that it can rebound efficiently, and let your crew stop it at the high point of the rebound.  You'll still have an energy loss for each shot, but for not much effort you'll maximize the overall energy efficiency of the system for multiple shots.

Thanks everyone. I actually had some errors in the spreadsheet that underestimated the potential energy transfer. Fixed it for now. Merry Christmas and Happy New Year.
